# Adding Realm to the project with Cocos 2d/3d results in No member named 'x' in '_GLKVector2 error'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocoapods, realm

I have a project with Cocos2D/3D installed via coping source files. Now I try to transform project to add Cocoa pods support. So I set the project - everything looks good but when I try to add to the pod

```
pod 'Realm', '0.89'
```

I got numerous linker errors like this:

```
...Cocos/cocos2d/cocos2d/CCRenderer.h:106:79: No member named 'x' in '_GLKVector2'
```

When I remove the realm pod - everything works well. How can I to force cocos and realm works together?

I investigated that real add this line to the project:

```
"OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS": "-std=c++1y $(inherited)"
```

without this realm not compiling - after adding this cocos shows errors during the compilation process..

Comment: Since there are so many possible Xcode build settings and configurations you may have used to set up your project with CocoaPods, Realm and Cocos2D, I've created a small sample project with Realm and Cocos2D installed via CocoaPods: https://static.realm.io/debug/CocosRealm.tgz. Could you compare that project's configuration with yours to see what may have been done differently? Please note that I had to modify Cocos2D slightly for it to compile.

Comment: There is also an example project showing how to use Realm with Cocos2D here: https://github.com/9loops/cocos2d-realm-io-xxtea